# Query string and attribute routing together for controller .NET core web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I trying to achieve something like this

```
namespace CoreAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string GetValue(string name,string surname)
        {
            return "Hello " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call this controller method by using both of these URLs:

1. http://localhost:11979/api/values/Getvalues/John/lawrance
2. http://localhost:11979/api/values/GetValues?name=john&surname=lawrance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve this by defining multiple routes on top of the controller method

```
[HttpGet("GetValues")]
[HttpGet("GetValues/{name}/{surname}")]
public string GetValue(string name, string surname)
{
    return "Hi" + name;
}
```

This will work with `http://localhost:11979/api/values/GetValues/John/lawrance` and `http://localhost:11979/api/values/GetValues?name=john&surname=lawrance`

To add more:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetValues")]
[Route("GetValues/{name}/{surname}")]
public string GetValue(string name,string surname)
{
    return "Hello " + name + " " + surname;
}
```

This also works.

Comment: "You can do one or the other in asp.net core" - So we can't do two types of routing on the single method.

Comment: [HttpGet]

[Route("GetValue")]

[Route("GetValue/{name}/{surname}")]

Adding route attribute also works for me.

Comment: Can we enable the query string routing on Global level, like in Startup.cs?

Comment: In .Net Core 5, the querystring path is not working correctly. I am getting default values (i.e. empty strings) on the query string path